# Escaping and double quotes together with Linq

Tags: c#, string, escaping, literals, double-quotes

I am making a small piece of code where I look for all nodes in XML containing  "folder name=\"u"" .
I have problems with the string literals, I tried with @ and escape or double quotes without any success. Here is the code :

```
public class Folders
{


public static IEnumerable<string> FolderNames(string xml, char startingLetter)
{
    string[] MyString;
    List<string> MyList = new List<string>();
    string item = "";

   StringSplitOptions.None)).ToList();

    MyString = xml.Split('>') ;

    var matchingvalues = MyString
.Where(stringToCheck => stringToCheck.Contains("<folder name=\\\""));

     return matchingvalues;
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string xml =
        "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>" +
        "<folder name=\"c\">" +
            "<folder name=\"program files\">" +
                "<folder name=\"uninstall information\" />" +
            "</folder>" +
            "<folder name=\"users\" />" +
        "</folder>";


      foreach (string name in Folders.FolderNames(xml, 'u'))
    Console.WriteLine(name);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

How should I write 
    var matchingvalues = MyString.Where(stringToCheck => stringToCheck.Contains("

?

Answer (score 1):

1. You're not even using your `startingLetter` parameter in `FolderNames`
2. You say you're looking for "folder name=\"u"", but your code looks for `"<"folder name=\\\""`. Disregarding the missing "u", you're looking for a literal backslash as well. Which doesn't exist in your xml. The backslashes in your xml are for escaping the quotes.
3. You haven't posted your real code because your method doesn't even work. WTF is this??

> ```
>    StringSplitOptions.None)).ToList();
> ```

4. You don't use the `item` variable.

Hopefully the above is enough to show where you went wrong. Better still, use .NET's xml parsing abilities to get the values. Currently your method lies; it doesn't just return "Folder Names", it returns a mess of half-xml as well.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem isn't really with the escaping.
But with the fact you reinvented the wheel a little bit.

There are multiple xml parsers in c#.

Linq to xml is one of them. with it you could write something simple like:

```
string xml =
  "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>" +
    "<folder name=\"c\">" +
        "<folder name=\"program files\">" +
            "<folder name=\"uninstall information\" />" +
        "</folder>" +
        "<folder name=\"users\" />" +
    "</folder>";

        XElement xElement = XElement.Parse(xml);
        IEnumerable<string>  values = xElement.
            Descendants("folder").
            Where(element => element.Attribute("name")?.Value?.StartsWith("u") == true).
            Select(element => element.Attribute("name").Value);
```